# Ansible The field 'password' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a problem when i try to launch ansible with this command:

```
ansible -i /etc/ansible/hosts -m ping 10.0.0.4 --vault-password-file /etc/ansible/.lorem
```

outpout:

```
10.0.0.4 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The field 'password' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'super_mdp' is undefined"
}
```

My hosts file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    10.0.0.4:
        ansible_password: "{{ super_mdp }}"
        ansible_shell_type: "sh"
        ansible_user: "user"
```

My vars file:

```
---
super_mdp: getrooted
```

Comment: `My vars file:` => where is that file stored exactly ?

Comment: Hi ! This file is in /etc/ansible/vars/main.yml 
I'm wondering, where can i put the path for telling this information to ansible ? ansible.cfg ?

Comment: As a first approach => `<inventory_dir>/group_vars/all.yml`. Now you might want to move there all your other variables as well. Note that you can also put several files in `<inventory_dir>/group_vars/all/whateverX.yml` and they will all be loaded (vault encrypted or not). See [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) for more details and to limit vars to certain hosts/groups.

Comment: As an alternative first approach, you can also go for => `<inventory_dir>/host_vars/10.0.0.4.yml`. Practicing with inventories will let you decide the exact place to store those vars depending on your exact requirements.